# Authorize.Net: How do I verify a hosted payment was successful once the user is redirected back to my site?

Tags: authorize.net, payment-processing

I am using the hosted form payment approach to accepting payments from users on my site. I dont see any examples of how to go about verifying the payment once the user is redirected back to my site. Here is how I'm trying to approach it:

1. Generate a token/form based on the cart
2. Post to the form url and send the user away
3. User returns to a verifying page
4. I have set up a webhook for all payment notifications
5. I receive the notification
6. ?????
7. Verify the payment status and price are correct
8. Navigate the user away from the verifying screen to the next page

In step 6 all i have is the token that was generated for the transaction and the webhook doesnt provide that token back to me. How do I say "this transaction belongs to this user who is waiting to be verified"?

Comment: you will probably have to state who the third party hosting provider for the payment options are.

Comment: Thanks, i set the tags but didn't put it in the title.

Comment: I am able to get the transaction details based on the transaction ID provided by the web hook, but how do I pass a GUID that will appear in that transaction so i can associate with the customer....

Comment: Ahhhhh maybe i can match on the email. I would need to capture that before they go to checkout and enter it again - there's got to be a more elegant solution. I have to believe this isnt a unique problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getTransactionDetailsRequest` in their [Transaction Reporting API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-details) to get the transaction details. The best place to put this information is in the `refTransId` field which is a value you can pass in as part of your transaction.